# how to remove special chars in div using angular 2?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Using html tags binding data in div's and div contains (ascii and special  characters) and Text can be dynamic or static.

How to achieve using angular 2?

how to specify that div should contains only text not other characters?

Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question to only ask a single distinct question.

Comment: Edited -->the question